# YAML parsing - c++

Tags: c++11, yaml

I'm very new to YAML and what to parse a file I have made and verified is of correct structure.  Here is the YAML:

```
---
DocType: DAQ Configuration File
# Creation Date: Wed Sep 21 10:34:06 2016
File Settings:
  - Configuration Path: /mnt/sigma/daqengine/config/
  - Configuration Name: daqengine.yaml
  - Build File Path: ./bld
  - Log File Path: ./log
  - Record H5 Files: true
Engine Data:
  - Make: EOS
  - Model: M280
  - Number of DAQs: 1
DAQ01 Settings:
  - IP Address: 192.168.116.223
  - Log DAQ Internal Temps: true
  - T0 Temp. Limit: 55
  - T0 Clear OTC Level Temp.: 50
  - T0 Sample Averaging: 5
  - T1 Temp. Limit: 60
  - T1 Clear OTC Level Temp.: 55
  - T1 Sample Averaging: 2
  - No. Layers Used: 1
DAQ01 Layer 0 Settings:
  - Model: AI-218
  - Sample Rate: 50000
  - Channels Used: 8
  - Channel01: HF Temp
  - Channel02: On-Axis PD
  - Channel03: Off-Axis PD
  - Channel04: X-Position
  - Channel05: Y-Position
  - Channel06: LDS
  - Channel07: Laser Power
  - Channel08: Unused
...
```

I need to extract the sequenced values to each key it is tagged to in C++.

Comment: @scraimer the edit you approved scrambled the YAML file into being invalid.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @Anthon Sorry about that; I had misinterpreted the format from the first revision. Thank you for fixing my mistake!

Comment: Thanks to the reformat that was updated.  This is exactly how my file looks.  As for my question I am using yaml-cpp and can load the yaml file and get to the Node level of "Engine Data", "DAQ01 Settings" and "DAQ01 Layer 0 Settings".  What I want to do is read in each of the Key/value pairs under each Node into a structure in memory using C++.